# Convert list of strings into multiple data types in one line

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I want to convert a list of strings into their correct types (ie. int, float, boolean, etc) in one line and unpack the values.

Is there a built-in module that can accomplish this better than the following?:

```
strLst = ["a", "1.0", "2", "True"]
a, b, c, d = [[s[0], float(s[1]), int(s[2]), bool(s[3])] for s in [strLst]][0]
```

EDIT:

I am creating a, b, c, d from a large text file and I was hoping there was an elegant way to make the conversion on one line. This is not just a question for this specific example but a question about a module that can accomplish something like this:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    a, b, c, d = [[s[0], float(s[1]), int(s[2]), bool(s[3])] \
                       for s in [next(f)[:-1].split()]][0]
```

Based on Niclas Nilsson's comment I could do the following:

```
a,b,c,d = [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in next(f)[:-1].split()]
```

Comment: If you didn't have that float in there I would suggest `[ast.literal_eval(s) for s in strLst]`

Comment: actually this is perfect based on my edit.

Comment: float seems to be working fine for me in 2.7?

Comment: Why does it need to be done in one line? it seems rather non-pythony since whatever solution you come up with is unlikely to make very readable code.

Comment: I felt that based on what I was trying to accomplish that there would be a module that would allow for a very compact and concise way to express this. As Niclas pointed above, this turned out to be true (61 characters). Is this not concise and Pythonic?

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson Ok, that's what comments are for I guess. Throw away some hints for an answer even though you haven't got time to really try it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zipping and applying cast functions works, and is much faster than literal_eval.

Also, literal_eval raises 'ValueError: malformed string' if the string value doesn't contain quotes, which, depending on your data, may be problematic.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from time import time
import ast

def zip_test():
    # Using StringIO to illustrate using something file-like.                   
    for row in StringIO('a 1.0 2 True\n' * 32):
        (a, b, c, d) = [f(v) for (f, v) in zip(
                (str, float, int, lambda v: v == 'True'), row.split())]

def ast_test():
    for row in StringIO('"a" 1.0 2 True\n' * 32):
        (a, b, c, d) = [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in row.split()]

for f in (zip_test, ast_test):
    start = time()
    for i in range(100):
        f()
    print '%s: %s' % (f.func_name, time() - start)


 # [ ** Results ** ]
 #
 # zip_test: 0.0131301879883
 # ast_test: 0.0835828781128
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL, now that is what I dreamed would be available when I asked this question. Thank You!

Comment: Replaced bool() with a lambda that returns True if string == 'True', and otherwise False. Applying bool() to 'True' or 'False' string values will always return True because they're both non-empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is too old. But my very first question is why it has to be a one-liner? I mean, even if the solution takes 100 lines, you can always put them under a function and call the function everywhere else and so the solution will be one-liner right?

I did came up with a two-liner which is faster and simpler than the suggested, if speed is of any necessity.

```
for row in StringIO('a 1.0 2 True\n' * 32):# Took the idea from derek's answer
    (a, b, c, d) = row.split(" ", 3)
    b, c, d = float(b), int(c), 'True' in d
```

As I mentioned, in case this cannot be used and you definitely need a one-liner, you can always do something like this:

```
def string_to_multiple_type_list(data):
    multi_list = []
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        a, b, c, d = line.split(" ", 3)
        multi_list.append([a, float(b), int(c), 'True' in d])
    return multi_list
```

And whenever you need the converted values, you can call it as one-liner:

```
new_multi_list = string_to_multiple_type_list(data)
```

Even though the function call takes a little time(definitely in micro seconds), it is faster and more elegant than using zip.

Borrowing derek's test code, I could see a 20% reduced time with this user defined function and 30% reduced time in case of two liner.