# how convert a string to list

Tags: python, string, list, text-parsing

I have a string like:

```
f = "[['jack', 2002, 100000, 'dollar']]"
```

I want to change it to a list but my output:

```
['[', '[', "'", 'j', 'a', 'c', 'k', "'", ',', ' ', '1', '3', '5', '6', ',', ' ', '1', '0', '0', ',', ' ', "'", 'd', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r', "'", ']', ']']
```

Can somebody help me:

my code:

```
f = "[['jack', 2002, 100000, 'dollar']]"
print(list(f))
```

what I expect:

```
[['jack', 2002, 100000, 'dollar']]
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of:
[Convert list of strings into multiple data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256639/convert-list-of-strings-into-multiple-data-types-in-one-line)

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(f)`

Comment: @Sean It's not a list of strings. It's one string that contains the printed representation of a list.

Comment: You cna use `eval`/`ast.literal_eval`, but you should *really consider why you have this string in the first place*. Where is this string coming from? Why do you find yourself in a position where you have a string that represents *python source code*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Given the contents, it's almost certainly the `repr` of a Python `list` (it uses single-quotes, so it's not legal JSON). I agree usually you want a better data serialization format.

Comment: @Sean: I found [the proper duplicate: "How to convert string representation of list to a list"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894269/364696), which is the "single string representing `list` to parsed `list` of things it represents" canonical.